# Effective sort-by-example algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Assume we have an array of objects of length N (all objects have the same set of fields).

And we have an array of length N of the same type values, which represent certain object's field (e.g. array of numbers representing IDs).

Now we want to sort the array of objects by the field which is represented in the 2nd array and in the same order as in the 2nd array.

For example, here are 2 arrays (as in description) and expected result:

```
A = [ {id: 1, color: "red"}, {id: 2, color: "green"}, {id: 3, color: "blue"} ]
B = [ "green", "blue", "red"]

sortByColorByExample(A, B) == 
    [ {id: 2, color: "green"}, {id: 3, color: "blue"}, {id: 1, color: "red"} ]
```

How to effectively implement 'sort-by-example' function? I can't come up with anything better then `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is assuming you have a bijection from elements in `B` to elements in `A`

Build a map (say `M`) from `B`'s elements to their position (`O(N)`)

For each element of `A` (`O(N)`), access the map to find where to put it in the sorted array (`O(log(N))` with a efficient implementation of the map)

Total complexity: `O(NlogN)` time and `O(N)` space

Comment: This turns out to be the same answer than Steve Jessop's

Comment: well, I haven't made the assumption of exactly one element in A per color. This is a good optimization for that case. I suppose you could consider it as a special kind of bucket sort, where you know that each bucket has 1 element, but that's the closest I came to mentioning it :-)

Comment: The OP mentions that A and B have the same size, so I thought this was a reasonable assumption.

Comment: True, I missed that. I think what's lacking from the question is a statement of whether the objects in `A` all have different colors. If they do, then your assumption necessarily holds. If they don't then it's messier, but I agree with you it looks as though it's intended that they do.

Comment: Unless of course if A and B have a different set of values, but then the output is not well defined...

Comment: Maybe Gareth Rees has understood the question better than either of us - his code copes with the case where the colors are repeated, provided B contains the same number of repeats of each color as A does. So given 3 red items and 4 blue ones, his code can sort them into order "red, blue, red, blue, blue, blue, red". It's basically arbitrary which red item is chosen for index 0, but as it happens his code choose whichever was last in A.

Comment: Maybe, however in that case the admissible output is not unique, but this is not necessarily an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we are sorting on an item's colour. Then create a dictionary *d* that maps each colour to a list of the items in A that have that colour. Then iterate across the colours in the list B, and for each colour *c* output (and remove) a value from the list *d*[*c*]. This runs in O(*n*) time with O(*n*) extra space for the dictionary.

Note that you have to decide what to do if A cannot be sorted according to the examples in B: do you raise an error? Choose the order that maximizes the number of matches? Or what?

Anyway, here's a quick implementation in Python:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def sorted_by_example(A, B, key):
    """Return a list consisting of the elements from the sequence A in the
    order given by the sequence B. The function key takes an element
    of A and returns the value that is used to match elements from B.
    If A cannot be sorted by example, raise IndexError.

    """
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for a in A:
        d[key(a)].append(a)
    return [d[b].pop() for b in B]

>>> A = [{'id': 1, 'color': 'red'}, {'id': 2, 'color': 'green'}, {'id': 3, 'color': 'blue'}]
>>> B = ['green', 'blue', 'red']
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted_by_example(A, B, itemgetter('color'))
[{'color': 'green', 'id': 2}, {'color': 'blue', 'id': 3}, {'color': 'red', 'id': 1}]
```

Note that this approach handles the case where there are multiple identical values in the sequence B, for example:

```py
>>> A = 'proper copper coffee pot'.split()
>>> B = 'ccpp'
>>> ' '.join(sorted_by_example(A, B, itemgetter(0)))
'coffee copper pot proper'
```

Here when there are multiple identical values in `B`, we get the corresponding elements in `A` in reverse order, but this is just an artefact of the implementation: by using a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead of a list (and `popleft` instead of `pop`), we could arrange to get the corresponding elements of `A` in the original order, if that were preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of arrays, call it C of size B.length.
Loop through A.  If it has color 'green' put it in C[0]. If it has a color of 'blue' put it in C[1], if it has a color of red put it in C[2].
When you're done go through C, and flatten it out to your original structure.

Comment: @Boundless: the step " If it has color 'green' put it in C[0]. If it has a color of 'blue' put it in C[1], if it has a color of red put it in C[2]" naively has `O(length(B))`, so it works but it might not be any better than what the questioner has already.

Comment: @SteveJessop The 'if' isn't an if statement.  This is pseudo code.  I was essentially saying the same thing that you did, just not as well as you did :-)

Comment: @Boundless: well, if you were saying the same thing as me then you do have what mmgp calls a "prior index", that's the map I describe ;-) At least, I think mmgp means "prior to processing A", not "prior to doing anything at all".

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, you definitely have to read through B before you process A

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something along the lines of a merge sort be better? Create B.length arrays, one for each element inside B, and go through A, and place them in the appropriate smaller  array then when it's all done merge the arrays together. It should be around O(2n)

Answer (score 0):

- Iterate through the first array and Make a `HashMap` of such fields versus the `List` of Objects. **O(n)** [assuming there are duplicate values of those key fields]

For eg. key = green will contain all objects with field value Green

- Now iterate through the second array, get the list of objects from HashMap and store it in another array. **O(k)** .. (where k - distinct values of field)

The total running time is O(n) but it requires some additional memory in terms of a map and an auxiliary array

In the end you will get the array sorted as per your requirements.